# Change to different condenser fan motor model?

Tags: hvac, fans, electric-motor

I have an HVAC system that has a condenser fan motor that has gone bad. The motor is no longer available. What considerations do I need to make in order to replace the motor with a different motor?

For example, if the voltage is the same, can I replace the motor with one that has similar speed? Would it just require a matching capacitor?

Additionally, can it be switched over to brushless?

Comment: Posting the brand/model of the piece of equipment that's failed will get you a better answer.

Comment: Thank you. I see a number of questions on this site for specific motors. I was hoping to get a feel for the approach that the experts take. From a circuits standpoint, it appears that the electrical interface allows for swapping as long as some basics are heeded. There's also the downstream considerations such as fan speed for moving enough heat. Looking for understanding of those things that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the unit was designed for a given capacity. To achieve this and maintain a proper temperature the fan was sized to give enough air flow to achieve this. The target is the airflow. The blade at a given RPM will give the airflow the manufacturer determined was needed. From this the horsepower was derived and the motor sized accordingly. Slowing down the airflow will cause the refrigeration system high side pressure to rise adding more load to the compressor. To much and byby compressor. If you speed it up that will keep the high side cool but also increase the horsepower required to turn the fan and if the motor does not have the capability it will also eventually fry. Increasing the fan speed will require the horsepower of the fan motor to increase by the cube of the speed ratio.

My recommendation is to match the RPM and motor. If you cannot a slightly motor larger motor with the same RPM will work assuming the electrical side will support it. If the motor requires a capacitor it is always wise to replace it with a new one of the correct size when changing the motor.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to **match** the RPM and the HP rating will need to match or exceed the original motor. Don't mess with "close enough" RPMs. Higher, and you will increase HP of motor needed by some unknown amount and potentially burn out motor. Or you will push the fan blade to RPMs it wasn't designed for and it could fail catastrophically. You will need a capacitor appropriate for the motor. You can use a brushless motor.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Do you have any technical sources you can reference? How do I know what capacitor to use? Also, I've seen mention that brushes doesn't need a capacitor, but need more info.

Comment: LMGTFY... here is an exhaustive reference for motor replacement https://thedealertoolbox.com/custom/assets/Files/FF001%20Fasco%20Facts.pdf

Comment: It sounds like you're being snarky with the LMGTFY. I did google it and found a bunch of unhelpful noise, so I came here for help. That said, the link that you reference is fantastic. What keywords did you search on?